# Ajax is having an error not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When the user first goes on website on the index route I will get the user's timezone.

I have an ajax request on my index.blade.html file at the route. "/"

I am posting the ajax route to this route "/custom_sessions".

**error im getting**

jquery-1.12.4.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom_sessions 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
// route the ajax is hitting

Route::post('/custom_sessions', 'CustomSessionsController@store');
```

-

```
// controller

class CustomSessionsController extends Controller
{

    public function store()
    {
        // when i remove this line the ajax request is successful with no errors in the console
        session('timezone' => $request('timezone'));
    }

}
```

-

```
// have this in my head in my html

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

-

```
// ajax script at the bottom of my index.blade.php file

$.ajax({

  headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
  },
  type: "POST",
  url: "/custom_sessions",
  data: {
      "timezone": "PST"
  }

});
```

Comment: Check the error log in `storage/logs/laravel.log`, or `storage/logs/laravel-2018-03-09.log` (if using `daily` log method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your issue:

```
session('timezone' => $request('timezone'));
```

is throwing a Syntax error. The first parameter is not an `array`, so using `=>` will throw

> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

It should be

```
session()->put("timezone", $request->input("timezone"));
```

The next issue is that your function doesn't use `$request`, so your `store()` function should be:

```
public function store(Request $request){
  session()->put("timezone", $request->input("timezone"));
}
```

Also, be sure to either reference `Request` directly:

```
public function store(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){ ... }
```

or add it as a `use` declaration at the top of your class:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CustomSessionsController extends Controller { ... }
```